# BootChamp no longer works on El Capitan, what's the fastest way to boot into Windows?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, macos

Ever since OS X El Capitan, BootChamp, the utility that let you directly restart into Windows from the menu bar (without needing to hold the option key) no longer works. The developer's explanation can be found [here.](http://kainjow.tumblr.com/post/128933657269/bootchamp-and-el-capitan)

**How can I quickly boot into Windows, ideally from the menu bar?**

Perhaps a way to package an AppleScript into a menu bar icon? I don't want to disable SIP just for BootChamp.

Comment: Interesting. I know Boot Runner supports BootCamp without needing SIP to be disabled on the Mac end. Do you see your windows image as a bootable option in the System Preferences Startup Disk preference pane?

Comment: @bmike I do. To clarify, Boot Camp is working perfectly fine with Windows 10. Boot Champ just let me skip the whole hold option while booting process, with a quick restart from within OS X. From the developer's note: "When clicking 'Restart into Windows' a 'Bless failed' error will show with 'Could not set boot device property' ... Apple’s documentation explicitly states that the bless tool can no longer be used due to SIP, so no update to BootChamp will be able to work around this issue." Thoughts?

Comment: Yes - the slow way might now be the fastest. I don't see disabling SIP as worth the trade off to have a fast restart, but you could do that as well I suppose.

Comment: Since we've lived without SIP until recently I personally would not have any issue switching it off if it makes my life easier. Especially if you do most of your work on Windows and are thus unlikely to encounter threats while running OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try to disable System Integrity Protection that came with El Captain. If you want to do so (at your own risk) see [Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless)](http://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away).

It's actually what they say on the link you've given :

> I believe this is from changes related to the new “rootless” or System Integrity Protection feature of El Capitan (more info). Whether it’s a bug or a feature is impossible to tell at this point. If it’s a bug, then that means Apple should be fixing it in a future point release, for example 10.11.1. If it’s a feature, they need to update their bless tool and remove the featureset entirely.

The rootless or System Integrity Protection is designed to deny app to edit system related files. The way that BootChamp works it that it uses the command `bless` to change the current booting disk. This doesn't work anymore with rootless enabled. Other softwares like Refind doesn't work anymore thanks to rootless. System Integrity Protection is there to prevent applications from damaging your computer. It's relatively safe to disable it, but make sure you know what apps are getting executed on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

- Open System Preferences
- Startup Disk
- *unlock the padlock (bottom left of the window) if is shows closed*
- Select the Windows OS
- Press restart

If you enable UI scripting, you could automate that via Automator as well.

Less good options would be to pick up a virtualization software package that lets you run from the BootCamp partition without needing to restart OS X. That would reduce the time to get into windows drastically at the cost of software and measurable but potentially negligible slow down in your performance.

Comment: I can't see the Windows OS in Startup Disk. How do I repair my startup disk?

Comment: @aeroxy The brute force would be to back up, wipe, and reinstall everything. Perhaps a new question with enough details to understand your situation might be worthwhile? The procedure to fix would be more clear once it's narrowed down what needs repair. It could be several things...

Comment: What's the non-brute-force way to do it?

Comment: That would depend on whether you're running Windows in legacy mode or EFI mode.